# How to implement replies to comments

Tags: php, database

I am wondering what is the best way to implement replies to a parent comment that are stacking infinitely.

Let's say my database looks like this:

```
Table               Columns
comments            comment_id | comment
comment_replies     comment_id | reply_to | comment
```

With this database, can I do this:

```
#1 Comment 1
       #2 Reply to #1
              #3 Reply to #2
                     #4 Reply to #3
                            ....
              #5 Reply to #3
                     #6 Reply to #5
                            ....
```

So far I have managed to do this for up to 1 reply by adding foreach `comments.comment_id` where is equal to `comment_replies.reply_to`. It works okay for up to 1 reply per a parent comment. Facebook reply system works the same way, but what if I want to add replies to other replies like in the example above?

Answer (score 0):

```
Table               Columns
comments            comment_id | comment
comment_replies     comment_id | reply_to | comment | isToReplay
```

Change your table like this. If your reply for a comment make it false, if it for another reply make it true.